# Facebook iframe page plugin doesn't work with "." (dot)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-iframe

I'm making use of the Facebook page plugin as described https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin that can be used to generate JS of an iframe.

This works fine using e.g. the default URL as "https://www.facebook.com/facebook" but if you try to change to use a facebook page name that contains a "." (a dot) as e.g. "https://www.facebook.com/david.batra" then that dot makes it no longer work. Can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the dot …

`https://www.facebook.com/david.batra` refers to a *user profile*.

The *page* plugin, nomen est omen, is for *pages*. Completely different things, in FB terminology.

(And no, there is no plugin to show a user profile on an external site.)